# Add a parameter, or create a new method?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a long established repository like this:

```
interface IDonutRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts();
}
```

It's been around for ages, and the `GetDonuts` method does what it says. Then one day I need to add a new screen that shows all the donuts in the database, and it turns out that the method has a hidden feature - it filters out all donuts where `stale = true`. But on my new screen, I want to show all of them, even the stale ones! What is the best approach here?

Assuming that this method is used all over the place, and the default behaviour needs to stay the same, is it best to add a new method called `GetAllDonuts` that doesn't do the filtering, or should I just add a `onlyFresh` parameter onto the `GetDonuts` method?

I'm guessing its just down to judgement, but I'm wondering if there are any more informed answers out there?

Comment: If your interface is used by code over which you have no control and cannot change, then you must not change the interface.  Instead, add a new interface which implements the first, and new clients should use the new interface.

Comment: p.s.  Method signatures in an interface cannot have access modifiers.  They are always public.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would overload the method creating a new overload that takes the `showStale` parameter and then modify the old method to use the new overload passing `false` for the parameter value.

The interface would look like:

```
interface IDonutRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts();
    public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts(bool showStale);
}
```

Or if you're using .NET 4.0, you can use an optional parameter:

```
interface IDonutRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts(bool showStale = false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not too worried about the implmentation though, just how the public interface should look...

Comment: The problem with this is that in both cases, any class that implements IDonutRepository will have to be changed.  That's fine if you have access to the code that implements the interfaces, but otherwise, this will not do.  In cases where clients implement your interface, you must not change the interface.  You have to create a new one, IDonutRepository2, which implements IDonutRepository.

Comment: @Richard - That's true and would be the case if the OP was simply giving the interface to clients to implement. In the case of the OP, though, it is fairly easy to infer that he has control of the code as well (or at least has the ability to force the functionality change) otherwise this wouldn't even be a question.

Comment: yes this is just the case where I have access to all the code and can change whatever I like, as this case is where the right thing to do seems least obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an optional parameter? This way you don't break existing code:

```
interface IDonutRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts(bool onlyFresh);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<Donut> GetDonuts(bool onlyFresh = false)
{
    if (onlyFresh)
        // do stuff
    else
        // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This really comes down to personal preference, to some extent...

If you have the ability to change the API, I would (personally) rename the current method in a way that makes it obvious that it is not returning all `Donut` instances.  My expectation would be that a repository's `GetDonuts` method would get all of the donuts.  This could be doing via a parameter, or a different name, at your discretion.

That being said, a method overload taking the extra parameter is probably the best option moving forward, if keeping compatibility is critical.  (This depends a lot on who and where this API is used...)

Comment: In general, changing signatures is a bad thing to do unless there's a strong reason to do so. You can break a lot of code that way and frustrate other developers using your class. Just make sure to comment things very well, that the default behavior is to NOT include stale donuts, and add the new method with the bool parameter

Comment: @MonkeyWrench: As I said, it depends on the scenario - however, reactoring to change the signature to be more clear, in the long run, is often a good change.  It can be painful, and there are definitely reasons to avoid it, but if the entire scenario is in your control, it's often still the best option IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the circumstancs, one might consider introducing a property for accessing the donuts.

```
interface IDonutRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Donut> Donuts { get; }
    .. or ..
    IQueryable<Donut> Donuts { get; }
}
```

It's fairly easy to implement this interface if you're using a Linq-savvy ORM like Entity Framework or NHibernate.

The old GetDonuts method could be renamed GetFreshDonuts(), or you could refactor calls to it into the form:

```
repository.Donuts.Where(x => !x.Stale)
```

Answer (score 0):

> One of the growing trends in software
>   design is separating interface from
>   implementation. The principle is about
>   separating modules into public and
>   private parts so that you can change
>   the private part without coordinating
>   with other modules. However, there is
>   a further distinction—the one between
>   public and published interfaces. This
>   distinction is important because it
>   affects how you work with the
>   interface.

http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/published.pdf